# Where, if at all, do statistics exist breaking down votes by race in British general elections?

Tags: election

Wikipedia's page for the 2012 US Presidential election has this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2012#Voter_demographics which breaks down votes by, inter alia, the voters' ethnic origin.

If something similar exists for UK elections, where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Runnymede Trust](http://www.runnymedetrust.org/) did a survey for the 2010 general elections, called the *Ethnic Minority British Election Survey (EMBES)*. They felt that minorities were not adequately counted in the main *British Election Survey(BES)*.

[This PDF](http://www.runnymedetrust.org/uploads/EMBES%20Voting%20Behaviour.pdf) gives an overview of the results, including this summary chart:

[image: embes vote chart]
<sup>Numbers (except in N rows) are percentages. For instance, 25% of Pakistani voters chose Lib-Dem candidates.</sup>

It seems that minority voters tend to overwhelmingly vote for the Labour party. Further details can be found in the report, and on the main Runnymede site. I can't find anything concrete saying whether they will conduct the same survey for the upcoming 2015 election, but I feel it's likely.

Answer (score -2):

In the uk all votes are cast anonymously.

When you enter the polling station you identify yourself to the presiding officer, who checks that you are on the register. You are then given a ballot paper, on which you make your vote, and drop into the ballot box.

Other than the list of names There is no way of identifying you.

https://www.gov.uk/voting-in-the-uk/polling-stations

After the election the Electoral services officer will have a list of who has voted and who has not. This 'Marked Register' is only available to certain people - in general that means elected representative, registered political parties, and academic organisations.  See page 38 of the document linked below for an accurate list.

http://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/57931/Part-H-Access-and-supply-November-2012.pdf

The only thing the marked register shows is the fact that you have voted, not who you voted for.

The electoral register only shows your name, address, possibly age or date of birth (if you are coming of age during the life of that register) and the register number.  It does not show you ethnic origin, religion, or any other information.

It is worth mentioning that the full register can also be requested by credit reference agencies, who use it for checking that you are resident at an address for financial purposes. They cannot get the marked register.

The issue of bme voters was in the news a little while ago. This link might be of interest

http://www.theguardian.com/politics/2013/aug/11/ethnic-minority-votes-decisive-general-election

Comment: The data on the Wikipedia page linked above is based on exit polls, not on voter records (which I'm assuming are anonymous, just like in the UK). In which case, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff   Hi. I did not link to Wikipedia, that was a link in the original question not my answer

Comment: @Steve Your assumption is correct, the only official US stats are vote totals for a precinct and political party registration (as part of the voter roll, which doesn't have race),  so the numbers use exit polls.

Comment: @mar The point is that the question asks for stats, not official stats. There can be unofficial statistics based on exit polls, like in the US. The Wikipedia page in the question is based on exit polls, so a proper answer should include them if relevant.

Comment: Under what circumstances would someone ask a question like my one, and not know that general elections ballots are secret?